# ServletException (JNLP JSP not found)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jnlp, servletexception

I'm developing a JWS application as an applet replacement. So far I've been able to launch my app from its parent application via a link in an HTML page to static JNLP. But my app really needs to be launched by dynamic JNLP since the argument values will be different with each execution. So I decided to extend the JnlpDownloadServlet in the manner shown [here][1]. My download servlet is called `download`, which is mapped to a URL pattern `\download` and which references a JSP called `myJnlp.jsp`, which currently contains some static JNLP, in the overriden method `service`:

```
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)        throws ServletException, IOException 
   {      
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
      resp.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file");
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/myJnlp.jsp").include(request, resp);
   }
```

When I try to invoke my download servlet, I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/myJnlp.jsp&quot; not found
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:417)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:384)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    com.myCompany.parentApp.myDownloadServlet.service
```

I placed `myJnlp.jsp` in the directory `jsp` which is the directory that contains the other JSPs used by the parent application. Did I put the JNLP page in the wrong location or did I specify it incorrectly in my servlet code?

Comment: According to the API; "If the path begins with a "/" it is interpreted as relative to the current context root."  So, you should try using request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/myJnlp.jsp").include(request, resp);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a subdirectory called `myJWSApp`, then I placed the JNLP JSP in that directory then referenced it as

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("myJWSApp/myJnlp.jsp").include(request, resp);
```

Thanks to @rickz whose comment pointed me in the right direction...